Why would Michael the Great Prince stand up unless he is seated on a throne?
Daniel 12:1

At that time Michael will stand up, the great prince who stands for the children of your people; and there will be a time of trouble

Is it correct to assert that Michael stands up because he is seated on a throne, which exposes his identity as someone of critical importance? Is there any relationship to Acts 7:55, where we see Jesus standing in a place of honour at God's right hand?
Why would he need to stand? Scripture states that angels stand around the Great White Throne and are not seated, which creates the understanding that they are not seated. What is so special about Michael that he should stand up to deliver God's saints?

Gabriel states that he 'stands in the presence of God' Luke 1:19 - due to his status as an angel. No angel would sit in the presence of God almighty. Only Jesus Christ, after righteous suffering in humanity, after resurrection and after ascension, and after invitation to do so 'sits' in God's presence and upon God's throne.

@NigelJ, Gabriel uses a term that shows this is a repetitive behavior, stands, this angel has been standing up for a people, he could have led this people out of Egypt, there is some truth to the angelomorphic nature of Jesus Christ.  The answer suggests its the war in heaven but that war is not about defending a people but blocking the access of Satan to heaven.

I've Edited the question to avoid Closing it - this is a Hermeneutics site. You shouldn't begin a question with three paragraphs of leading material suggesting your preferred conclusion before you even get to the text. If the idea arises naturally from the text, you don't need to worry about convincing people about it before they even read it.


Is it correct to assert that Michael stands because he is sited on a throne,

My understanding of the logic of the question is:

Jesus is seated on a throne at the right hand of God
Daniel 12:1 says that Michael "shall stand up"
Stand up means that Michael was seated
Seated means that there must have been a throne


Therefore, Because both Jesus and Michael are seated on a throne - Jesus and Michael are the same person.

The logic is based on the assumption that "stands" is a physical action of moving from seated on a throne to a standing position.
Even as a physical action standing from a seated position is not the only option.
Michael could move from:
Kneeling to standing
Lying down to standing
Walking to standing still
The question also assumes that if Michael was seated that it would have to have been on a throne rather than a chair or a bench or cross legged on the floor.
It is important to respect Daniel as we read his words by seeking to understand what he meant by what he wrote.
Looking at the text:
Daniel 12:1 NKJV

“At that time Michael shall stand up,
The great prince who stands watch over the sons of your people;
And there shall be a time of trouble,
Such as never was since there was a nation,
Even to that time.
And at that time your people shall be delivered,
Every one who is found written in the book.

A person who "stands watch" is not a person who is moving from a seated position to a standing position. It is someone who is performing guard duty.
"At that time Michael shall stand up" Refers to a time when Michael will take a stand and deliver God's people. The meaning is more that Michael will move into a battle position in order to take action. Michael will stand forth or take a stand for those he guards.
Other translations capture this meaning more clearly:
Here are some alternative "word for word" or literal translations.
Daniel 12:1 ESV

“At that time shall arise Michael, the great prince who has charge of your people. And there shall be a time of trouble, such as never has been since there was a nation till that time. But at that time your people shall be delivered, everyone whose name shall be found written in the book.

NASB

“Now at that time Michael, the great prince who stands guard over the sons of your people, will arise. And there will be a time of distress such as never occurred since there was a nation until that time; and at that time your people, everyone who is found written in the book, will be rescued.

Daniel says that "at that time" Michael will move into position to guard and rescue God's people. There is no mention of a throne and the intent is not to describe the physical act of standing but to describe the tactical status of being ready, in position. The point of the passage is that God will protect his people during "a time of distress such as never occurred..." and that God's people will be rescued.
The text does not support Michael being seated on a throne or a connection between Michael and Jesus being the same person.

you have reasoned logically to suggest other possibilities that I was ignoring

@SoFewAgainstSoMany - brother, הָעֹמֵד֮ (hā·‘ō·mêḏ) means to arise, to stand up. Michael stands up and is sent down with the Father's angels to deliver the saints, just as Christ stands up and returns with the Father's angels to deliver the saints.

From Strongs H5975 (‛âmad), to figuratively 'stand up' or "serve". Daniel 12:1 is in reference to Michael fighting Satan (the dragon) for Israel (the woman) in Revelation 12, the "war in heaven".
Revelation 12:6-10

And the woman fled into the wilderness, where she hath a place prepared of God, that they should feed her there a thousand two hundred and threescore days.
7 And there was war in heaven: Michael and his angels fought against the dragon; and the dragon fought and his angels,
8 And prevailed not; neither was their place found any more in heaven.
9 And the great dragon was cast out, that old serpent, called the Devil, and Satan, which deceiveth the whole world: he was cast out into the earth, and his angels were cast out with him.
10 And I heard a loud voice saying in heaven, Now is come salvation, and strength, and the kingdom of our God, and the power of his Christ: for the accuser of our brethren is cast down, which accused them before our God day and night.

So no, Michael is not literally sitting on the throne of Jesus Christ.

Well answered, So Michael does fight and in doing so he stands up for Christians? Why would Michael stand up for Christians when its Jesus who bought them with his blood?

@SoFewAgainstSoMany It is Israel, who must "endure unto the end" of their remaining seven prophetic years of tribulation, that Michael stands up for, not us the church, the body of Christ, who live in the Ephesians 3:2 age of God's grace.

so we are currently in God's age of grace?

@SoFewAgainstSoMany Yes, until the last believer believes and fills the church, the body of Christ. Romans 11:25
"For I would not, brethren, that ye should be ignorant of this mystery, lest ye should be wise in your own conceits; that blindness in part is happened to Israel, until the fulness of the Gentiles be come in."

The Bible doesn’t specifically say that Jesus or any being is seated on a throne because Strong’s G1722 can just as well mean that Jesus is seated by the throne. Only one can sit in the throne unless we have a Santa Claus and little kid sitting on Santa’s lap situation.
The second misconception is that Christ must be specially only one being, or perhaps one person. The Messiah is an army, a group of bodies in the plural sense.
The prince of the world was cast out, and the Spirit of Truth is now the judge. The judge sits on the throne.
John 14:31
but he (the prince of this world) comes so that the world may learn that I (Jesus) love the Father and do exactly what my Father has commanded me.
Michael is the prince of the world. He is cast out of heaven to teach the world the truth. Jesus is not the Spirit of Truth. He came not to judge the world. John 12:47
Whatever specific title and role the angels have can change. It has nothing to do with Satan and demons and evil in the gospel of John. The angels are the sons of God doing whatever the Father requests. The angels gather around the throne both kneeling and standing. The Father is the angel with the greatest authority which could also mean the Son is one with the Father when the Son has been given all authority. Matthew 28:18. Which angel becomes the Father, Son, Spirit of Truth, prince of this world is not exactly set in stone as permanent job security. Jesus spoke about the angels, not YHWH.

"The Messiah is an army" - Citation needed.

The Messiah is the holy people in Daniel 7.

The Most High if GOD itself cannot be appointed nor annointed by the people and so cannot be a Messiah in the literal sense. The holy people would either be the messiah themselves as a group or have to appoint and anoint a leader as the messiah. The appointing with political choice and anointing with oil is very much a physical act with religious and political ceremonies

It’s all nonsense. Israel is amongst the authorities as the weakest military in the world.

I think you must be confusing it with another passage - Daniel only mentions the messiah in chapter 9, where 'messiah the prince... will be cut off'. Messiah is a technical term in Hebrew with a lot of academic debate around how exactly it should be understood in different passages - citations would be helpful so that the reader can understand why you're making a claim and what kind of evidence there is around it.

the Messiah is not an army
